# Is the ideal generated by two irreducible polynomials prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let be $K$ a field. I would like to know, if $p(x,y), q(x,y)\in K[x,y]$ are irreducible polynomials then, is the ideal $I=(p(x,y), q(x,y))$ prime?

I tried simple polynomials and everything aims to this being true. Moreover, it seems that the equivalence holds. However, I do not know how to proceed with a proof...

Comment: $(y-x^2, y+x^2)=(y,x^2)$.

Comment: thank you so much! @SassatelliGiulio

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio in the case $(y,x^2+a)$  and $x^2+a$ irreducible, would the ideal be prime?...

Comment: The quotient is isomorphic to $K[x]/(x^2+a)$, so it's maximal.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio could you show me the isomorphism?

Comment: Well, quotienting out by $(y)$ gets rid of all the $y$ terms, hence $K[x,y]/(y)\cong K[x]$. In $K[x]$, because $x^2+a$ is irreducible, the ideal $(x^2+a)$ is maximal among all principal ideals of $K[x]$. But $K$ is a field, so $K[x]$ is a PID. Hence $(x^2+a)$ is maximal. Note that in a PID maximal and prime ideals coincide (except sometimes for $(0)$, specifically when the PID is not a field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we have counter example:
Let $I_1 = (y^2 - x^3)$ and $I_2 = (y)$ be prime ideals in $R = k[x,y]$, where k is real field.

$I$= ($y^2$-$x^3$, $y$) is not a prime ideal becouse $R/I$ is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^3)$, which is not integral domain. Hence $I$ is not prime.